# Magnify (zoom) part of image application

Tags: photos, gallery, zooming

I'd like to edit an image to add a "magnifying glass" ring with a magnified region inside, like in the screenshot below. The standard Gallery editing tools can't do that, and I've tried a few other apps with the same result. Is there any way to add this effect (zoom certain part of image) using any kind of Android app?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

use this
https://github.com/nomanr/android-image-magnifier

may u like this...................... ............. ............. .............

Comment: While this looks promising, it's a component for devs to use, not an app immediately ready for regular users.